# How to open pop up window from a model popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
window.open
```

above method doesn't work when i call it from model pop up.Is there any alternate to open a popup window over model pop up?   Thanks in advace.

Comment: u can use this jquery plugin http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/05/javascript-popup-box/

Comment: or this one http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: i want to open popup from already opened model pop up.

Comment: can you provide the source code or jsfiddle url for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You just simply call your model popup again it will work , it will consider your current popup as a parent window if you set your current popup type `iframe` . It doesn't work with ajax